# GitHubで特定のリポジトリにだけアクセスできるSSH Keyを作成したい

Tags: github, ssh

こんにちは。

GitHubで特定のリポジトリにだけアクセスできるSSH Keyを作ることは可能でしょうか。
なぜなら自分のユーザーで普通にSSH keyを作成した場合、
無関係なリポジトリまでのアクセスを許可してしまうことになるからです。
（権限が強すぎるという言葉が正しいと思います）

イメージとしてはAWSのIAMのようなものが欲しいと思っています。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: はじめまして。回答を投稿させて頂いたものですが、特定のリポジトリーだけアクセスするためのSSH Keyは手段の一つであって、目的はGitHubでリポジトリー毎にアクセス権をユーザー（チーム）別にコントロールしたいのだと思います。もしそうであればその様にタイトルを編集して、修正していただけるとより適切な回答が得られるかと思いますので、タイトルの修正を検討してみて下さい。

Comment: 返信が遅くなり申し訳ありません。
こちら、タイトル通りの意図でして、別の方が回答されている `Deploy keys` により実現可能でした。
私にリポジトリの管理権限がないため、見えていなかっただけです。
ご回答ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

特定の単一リポジトリへのRead権、あるいはRead / Write権を持つSSH鍵を作るのであればリポジトリの設定から **Deploy keys** を設定できます。名前の通りデプロイ用鍵ですが、そのような使い方もできなくもないです。

ただし、これはあくまでも1つのSSH鍵を単一のリポジトリにしか利用できません。もし複数のリポジトリにアクセスする権限が必要なのであれば別途アカウントを用意するなどの手段を取る必要があります。

Comment: 返信が遅くなり大変申し訳ございません。
`Delopy keys` の件承知しました。これで望んでいた環境が作れます。
ありがとうございました。

Comment: @garisan  この回答で解決した場合、是非回答を承認してください。回答の左側のチェックをクリックするだけです。これではじめて解決済みの質問となります。[回答を承認するとどうなりますか？ - スタック・オーバーフローMeta](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1735/%E5%9B%9E%E7%AD%94%E3%82%92%E6%89%BF%E8%AA%8D%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E3%81%A8%E3%81%A9%E3%81%86%E3%81%AA%E3%82%8A%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99%E3%81%8B)

Answer (score 1):

GitHubはユーザーアカウントに対してSSHKeyを登録することになるのでそれは難しいと思います。
ただし、GitHubには、組織アカウントを作成する機能もあるので、組織アカウントを利用してはいかがでしょうか。
こちらにも、public repositoryオンリーの無料プランがあるのでお試しが出来、各リポジトリーに対してメンバー・チーム毎のアクセス権を設定出来ます。
[GitHub - 組織の管理](https://git-scm.com/book/ja/v2/GitHub-%E7%B5%84%E7%B9%94%E3%81%AE%E7%AE%A1%E7%90%86)
という説明ページもあるので、@garisan さんの期待に添うものかどうか、確認してみることをお勧めします。